# transfering a variable to another page in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

Im trying to transfer a string-variable to another page. In Main Page code looks like:

```
 Page p1 = new Page1();
 NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 p1.lalala("sdfsdfsd");
```

in Page1 code looks like:

```
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void lalala(string i)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = i;
    }
}
```

and of course, nothing happens, textblock remains empty. and should not, i know.
i really don't know how i can quickly transfer to another page the value of a variable.
I say thanks in advance and sorry for really stupid question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283565/saving-variables-wp7/5284429#5284429

Comment: sorry for repeating the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass it on the uri in navigate, like

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml?lalala=sdfsdfsd", UriKind.Relative));
```

and then retrieve it from the query string in the navigation event in `Page1`

```
string lalala = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["lalala"];
textBlock.Text = lalala;
```

Comment: oh, sorry, but when i put this code to Page1(){}, i see "unhandled exception in ' "System.NullReferenceException"'"

Comment: and when i put this code to protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e), is nothing happens with textblock.

Comment: sorry, we have late night, so I thought a bit. figured out. Thank you again! :D